# How to use not common fonts in a website?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I have seen some pages using "weird" fonts.

One of them, is called `MuseoSlab500Regular`. How can i do in order use it at my styles?

Do i need to load the font from somewhere to be rendered in all the clients without problems?

I have been looking at the code of this website to figure it out but i couldn't find frmo where they load the `MuseoSlab500Regular` font:

http://theme-fusion.com/avada/

Regards

Comment: You have tagged the question *webfonts* but could not be bothered to investigate more based on that keyword? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/webfonts/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're using @font-face to load that font.

Look at this css file:

http://theme-fusion.com/avada/wp-content/themes/Avada/css/all.css

At the top you'll see the css code being used:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular';
src: url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Museo_Slab_500-webfont.svg#MuseoSlab500Regular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to use 'weird' fonts you need to add them to your server and use them from there because not every use has all the fonts installed on their computer. One good way to do this is  fontface : http://www.font-face.com/